# Javascript serializer throwing out of memory exception C#

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a C# method which converts datatable to JSON format which works fine for small data, but in case of more than 20000 records, it gives out of memory exception.
When I calculated the length of string that it is returning, it was just 1.3MB, still it is giving out of memory exception.

plaese help.

```
 public string DataTableToJSON(DataTable dt)
    {
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }

        json.MaxJsonLength = 2147483647;
        return json.Serialize(rows);
    }
```

Comment: You're creating a `Dictionary<string, object>` for each row. That's a lot of dictionaries. Add the fact that `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` is not the most memory-friendly (or best-performing) implementation and you have a fairly high chance of  memory blowout.

Comment: Thanks @Corey please suggest me an alternative, should I break my datatable into smaller datatables and combine the results or any other solution? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

With that many rows, all of the temporary `Dictionary<>` instances you're creating and so on, it's not terribly surprising that problems might arise... although the limits of what you can do this way are surprisingly high, large or complex record types tend to blow up the memory cost pretty quickly.

Normally when faced with a scaling problem like this I'll try to convert to a streaming implementation. In this case that would mean converting each row and appending it to an output buffer - a `StringBuilder` or some sort of `Stream`. We can use the `JavaScriptSerializer` to do the actual conversion to JSON, just in smaller chunks.

For testing I'm using a `DataTable` generated like this:

```
static DataTable GenerateTable()
{
    var result = new DataTable();
    result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)));
    result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Guid", typeof(Guid)));
    result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Timestamp", typeof(DateTime)));
    result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Text", typeof(string)));
    for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++)
        result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn($"Empty {j}", typeof(int)));
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
    {
        result.Rows.Add(i, Guid.NewGuid(), DateTime.Now, "This is a test.");
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

For this table, even at 100,000 rows, your original code works fine. Not sure what sort of structure you have to your data, or the limitations of your computer, but this generates ~25MB worth of JSON output. I checked `Environment.WorkingSet` after creating the table and after generating the JSON to get a *very* rough idea of how much memory this was using: ~140MB.

The first thing I tried was to stream a row at a time, using `JavaScriptSerializer` to handle each row and adding some appropriate framing:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("[");
bool first = true;
var row = new Dictionary<string, object>();

foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
{
    row.Clear();
    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    {
        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
    }
    if (!first)
        sb.Append(",");
    first = false;
    sb.Append(ser.Serialize(row));
}
sb.Append("]");
json = sb.ToString();
```

This reduced the `WorkingSet` delta down to around 100MB, as well as improving the run time by a bit (~15%). Since that worked fairly well the next step was to use the serializer just to handle each of the values:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("[");
bool firstRow = true;

foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
{
    sb.Append("{");
    if (!firstRow)
        sb.Append(",");
    firstRow = false;
    var firstCol = true;
    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    {
        if (!firstCol)
            sb.Append(",");
        firstCol = false;
        sb.Append($"\"{col.ColumnName}\":");
        sb.Append(ser.Serialize(dr[col]));
    }
    sb.Append("}");
}
sb.Append("]");
json = sb.ToString();
```

This got a tiny improvement in speed for roughly the same memory footprint. It also enables me to do fun things like skipping null values if I want to reduce the output... which cuts both runtime and memory usage significantly.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. I will try it out.